# Configuring Topology manager to new database running in different machine in sdl web 8

Tags: web8

Currently we have both Content Manager database and Topology Manager database running on same machine.

We have a plan of creating a new database on RDS for CM and Topology Manager.we have configured CM database to RDS by changing configuration settings in SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration.

How can I change topology manager database to new database on RDS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Navigate to %Tridion_Home%\TopologyManager\web
2. Unprotect database section in web.config
3. Change database settings in  node in web.config
4. Protect config file
5. Restart IIS

To unprotect database node user should execute following command from command line:

`%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "database" .`
(with dot at the end)

To protect it again:

```
%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "database" %Tridion_Home%\TopologyManager\web -prov TridionRsaProtectedConfigurationProvider
```

Comment: Worth noting that you will need to change directory to the `%Tridion_Home%\TopologyManager\web` folder in the command line before executing the script to unprotect the database strings. Make sure to backup the `web.config` file first too!